# Use Google Drive as app backup

Tags: android, backup, google-drive-api, android-sdk-tools

At Google I/O 2013 times, I read that there were new API to store big app data on user's Google Drive, in a hidden folder that user could always delete... I can't find the API and neither recall the name of the feature... can you help me, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The folder you mention is called Application Data folder, the basics are explained on https://developers.google.com/drive/appdata

Comment: Can we use this to backup and restore db files and shared preferences of our android application ? If yes could you please tell the steps ?